# Vue 2 arguments in inline (in-template) event handler

Tags: vue.js

Is it possible to access arguments/parameters passed to an emitted event within an inline / in-template handler? Something like:

```
<component @some-event="someObject.field = $arguments[0]"></component
```

What I'm trying to do exactly is assign a value to an object in the scope. I know I can create a method to do that and use it as a handler for the event but I was wondering if this could work as an inline statement.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It is not `$arguments[0]`, but just `arguments[0]` (without the $). I am surprised that it actually works in the inline handler. So the following code is valid and will work:

```html
<component @some-event="someObject.field = arguments[0]"></component>
```

The docs for [Methods in Inline Handlers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers) specifies `$event` as a special variable that gets the first parameter passed via event. I have always used it till now.

After reading your question, a bit more research led me to this reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

It seems every javascript function has a local variable called `arguments`, which is used when a function is expected to get variable number of arguments.

Using `arguments[]` as inline statements is definitely possible, but not documented anywhere in the context of vue.js framework. On the other hand, if you use `$event` in inline handler for events, it feels safer as it is documented clearly and will not break in a future version of Vue.js

Sample usage for `$event`:

```html
<component @some-event="someObject.field = $event"></component>
```

Answer (score 0):

> There is something that not many people know.
>   Inline handler besides the `$event` has access to `arguments`.

For example I was using `v-dropzone` which is passing many arguments (e.g. file, response).

By using

```
<v-dropzone @some-event="callMethod($event, 'some other arg')" >
```

will catch only the first argument.

So the solution was:

```
<v-dropzone @some-event="callMethod(arguments, 'some other arg')" >
```

Comment: what is arguments?

Comment: @mathtick checkout this: https://dev.to/rolanddoda/8-secrets-vue-developers-must-know-5la#inline-statement-handler-handle-multiple-arguments