# Vue 2 - receive event arguments and scope variable in event handler

Tags: vue.js

In Vue 2, I'm trying to use a custom event handler that receives arguments from a component *and* receives the current index (from `v-for`) as an argument.

I've found several ways to do this (hat-tip to [Vue 2 arguments in inline (in-template) event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40481651/vue-2-arguments-in-inline-in-template-event-handler)), but they all seem to depend on implementation details of Vue. Here's what I'm trying to do (the commented-out HTML also works):

```js
Vue.component('product', {
  template: '<button @click="handleClick">Do Fun Stuff</button>',
  methods: {
    handleClick: function() {
      this.$emit('fun-stuff', 'foo', 'bar');
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    callbackData: '',
    items: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  },
  methods: {
    handleFunStuff: function() {
      var argString = Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, ' ');
      this.callbackData = this.message + ' - ' + argString;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <p>{{message}}</p>
  <template v-for="(i, index) in items">
    <product @fun-stuff="function(stuff, things) { handleFunStuff(index, stuff, things) }">
    </product>
    <!--
      <product @fun-stuff="handleFunStuff(index, arguments[0], arguments[1])">
      </product>
      -->
    <!--
      <product @fun-stuff="handleFunStuff.bind(null, index).apply(null, arguments)">
      </product>
      -->
  </template>
  <p>{{callbackData}}</p>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

Is there a more proper way to do this in Vue?

Coming from Angular 1, this is possible (since component callback arguments are named) and (in my experience) used commonly.

Comment: I think your approach is fine, and is the Vue way to do this.

Comment: @CodinCat I had a couple approaches in there. Do you mean the `function(stuff, things) { handleFunStuff(index, stuff, things) }` or `handleFunStuff(index, arguments[0], arguments[1])` approach?

Comment: Oh I meant the highlighted one, it's easier to read, and the child doesn't need to be aware of the index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use the special [`$event` argument.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on)

[Here's a Codesandbox showing it in action.](https://codesandbox.io/s/o3y4jpn85)

Answer (score 1):

You should pass `index` as a `prop` to the component.

```js
Vue.component('product', {
  template: '<button @click="handleClick">Do Fun Stuff</button>',
  props: ['idx'],
  methods: {
    handleClick: function () {
      this.$emit('fun-stuff', this.idx, 'foo', 'bar');
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    callbackData: '',
    items: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  },
  methods: {
    handleFunStuff: function() {
      var argString = Array.from(arguments).join(' ');
      this.callbackData = this.message + ' - ' + argString;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <p>{{message}}</p>
  <template v-for="(i, index) in items">
    <product :idx=index @fun-stuff="handleFunStuff">
    </product>
  </template>
  <p>{{callbackData}}</p>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: Whoops, should've mentioned that in my question. I knew that was an option, but I was hoping to avoid it. It seems like the index is outside the component's area of concern? I suspect this answer is the "correct" one though.

Comment: The fact that it's an index is outside the component's area of concern, but you want the component to be individually identifiable, so you have to provide it with an identifier.