# VUE2 passing parameter from child to parent

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, emit

how do i properly pass parameter from child to parent with an $emit function?
here what i have done

**HTML**

```
<lista-servizi-gialla :servizi="modello" v-on:centramappa="mappaCenter(x,y,selected)"></lista-servizi-gialla>
```

**COMPONENT**

```
template'
<span class="pull-right forward"
 v-on:click="centraNellaMappa(single.x,single.y,single.selected)"></span>',

methods:{
    centraNellaMappa : function(x,y,selected){
        this.$emit('centramappa',[x],[y],[selected]);
     }  
}
```

**PARENT FUNCTION**

```
mappaCenter : function(x,y,selected){
    alert(x);
}
```

the 'x' parameter seems not being recognized

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually you are almost there, the only problem is the writing style you used for inline custom events handler.

```
v-on:centramappa="mappaCenter(x,y,selected)"
```

vue will look for x, y and selected variables in vue instance (`this.x` ...). Since you didn't define them in your instance, errors thrown.
So you have 3 solutions to solve this problem.

1. The easiest one. You can just pass method name like this.
   `v-on:centramappa="mappaCenter"`
   vue will match the method automatically and pass the arguments for you. See demo below.

```js
Vue.component('lista-servizi-gialla', {
  template: `
<span class="pull-right forward"
 v-on:click="centraNellaMappa(3, 5, true)">
test 
</span>
  `,
  methods:{
    centraNellaMappa : function(x, y, selected) {
      this.$emit('centramappa', [x], [y], [selected]);
    }  
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    mappaCenter: function(x, y, selected){
      //alert(x);
      console.log(`x: ${x}, y: ${y}, selected: ${selected}`);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<lista-servizi-gialla v-on:centramappa="mappaCenter"></lista-servizi-gialla>
</div>
```

2. You can also wrap your arguments into an object. Vue provides a special variable called `$event`, its value will be set as the first argument you passed in `$emit` event.
   `v-on:centramappa="mappaCenter($event)"`
   See demo below.

```js
Vue.component('lista-servizi-gialla', {
  template: `
<span class="pull-right forward"
 v-on:click="centraNellaMappa(3, 5, true)">
test 
</span>
  `,
  methods:{
    centraNellaMappa : function(x, y, selected) {
      this.$emit('centramappa', {x, y, selected});
    }  
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    mappaCenter: function({ x, y, selected }){
      //alert(x);
      console.log(`x: ${x}, y: ${y}, selected: ${selected}`);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<lista-servizi-gialla v-on:centramappa="mappaCenter($event)"></lista-servizi-gialla>
</div>
```

3. If you insist on keeping `mappaCenter` method in current form, you can use arguments variable which is defined in JavaScript spec.
   `v-on:centramappa="mappaCenter(...arguments)"`
   or
   `v-on:centramappa="mappaCenter(arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2])"`
   See demo below and check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40485023/6279569) for more information.

```js
Vue.component('lista-servizi-gialla', {
  template: `
<span class="pull-right forward"
 v-on:click="centraNellaMappa(3, 5, true)">
test 
</span>
  `,
  methods:{
    centraNellaMappa : function(x, y, selected) {
      this.$emit('centramappa', [x], [y], [selected]);
    }  
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    mappaCenter: function(x, y, selected){
      //alert(x);
      console.log(`x: ${x}, y: ${y}, selected: ${selected}`);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<lista-servizi-gialla v-on:centramappa="mappaCenter(arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2])"></lista-servizi-gialla>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you man! the second choice seems the most versatile to me, the documentation is not so clear on that point

Comment: @PdsInk Yep, it may be a little obscure.

Comment: @choasia Went with option one.